# How to add checkbox to qml treeview？

Tags: checkbox, qml, treeview

I added checkboxes through the treeview's itemDelegate property, but when I want to click on the parent node to select the child node, I find that I won't do it. .

```
 TreeView {
       id: treeView
       anchors.fill: parent
       frameVisible: false
       anchors.top: mainToolBar.bottom; anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
       anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 1
       model: sysConfig

       itemDelegate:CheckBox{

           id:checkbox
           indicator.height: 20
           indicator.width: 20
           text: styleData.value}}
```

Comment: can you please provide [mcve]?

Comment: Didn't the tree view get removed from QtQuick? I can only find it documented for `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` which is very old.

Comment: Yes, there is no official statement that it is deprecated.